# Override WebResource javascript method - WebForm_InitCallback()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, callback, embedded-resource

I am stuck with callbacks and multi-select select controls in ASP.NET. As I noticed, Microsoft has a bug since 2006(!) and when I performed a callback on a multiselect with selections of 1,2,3, the postback data is 1,1,1. 
I have identified the issue and it is in the following method:

```
function WebForm_InitCallback() {
    var formElements = theForm.elements,
        count = formElements.length,
        element;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            element = formElements[i];
            var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (tagName == "input") {
                var type = element.type;
                if ((__callbackTextTypes.test(type) || ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && element.checked))
                && (element.id != "__EVENTVALIDATION")) {
                    WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
                }
            }
        else if (tagName == "select") {
            var selectCount = element.options.length;
                for (var j = 0; j < selectCount; j++) {
                var selectChild = element.options[j];
                if (selectChild.selected == true) {
                    WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (tagName == "textarea") {
            WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
        }
    }
}
```

`element.value` does not pass the correct value, but `selectedChild.value` in "select" tags.

Even though I have found the problem, and I know how to override this method, I am not confident that this will work. Is it correct to override JavaScript methods that come from resources? Do you advice me to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is considered legacy by Microsoft and won't be fixed unless they consider it a critical issue.

Their workaround is to implement a custom http module to correct the code before sending it to the browser.

1. Create custom http module
2. Implement ReleaseRequestState event
3. Put following code in there:

   ```
   void context_ReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;

       if (application != null)
       {
           if (application.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("WebResource.axd"))
           {
               #region Set private value of HttpWriter so we can write to output stream
               //See http://daniel-richardson.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-apply-filter-to-content-returned.html
               var response = application.Context.Response;
               var httpWriterField = typeof(HttpResponse).GetField("_httpWriter",
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
               var ignoringFurtherWritesField = typeof(HttpWriter).GetField("_ignoringFurtherWrites",
                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
               var httpWriter = httpWriterField.GetValue(response);
               ignoringFurtherWritesField.SetValue(httpWriter, false);
               #endregion

               //We need to read filter property first or we get exception
               var f = application.Response.Filter;

               application.Response.Filter = new ResponseFilter(application.Response.OutputStream);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create class ResponseFilter which inherits from Stream class.

Constructor:

```
public ResponseFilter(Stream responseStream)
    {
        ResponseStream = responseStream;
    }
```

Write method:

```
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);

        string fixedOutput = output.Replace(@"if (selectChild.selected == true) {
                WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);", "if (selectChild.selected == true) {WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, selectChild.value);");

        byte[] fixedBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fixedOutput);


        ResponseStream.Write(fixedBuffer, 0, fixedBuffer.Length);
    }
```

- When implementing other abtract methods just simple call ResponseStream's methods

[source](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594413/multiple-select-does-not-return-correct-form-data-during-callback)

Comment: this is the working solution. Thanks. Something, that took me a lot of time to resolve. In case you have
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/> in your web.config, in order to encode the stream you need to have dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false".